# Way to access field in enclosing method from a anonymous inner class with naming ambiguity

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

Imagine the following setup:

```
public class MyClass
{
    final int field = 1; // f1

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int field = 2; // f2

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            final int field = 3; // f3

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

The variable `field` exists three times, each time in different scopes. In theory all three fields should be accessible in the `run` method of Runnable.

Accessing two of them (*f1* and *f3*) is easy enough (with simply `field` and `MyClass.this.field` respectively) however I could not find a way to access *f2*.

I am obviously aware that this is terrible design and should not ever happen in a production environment, however it intrigued me if there was a possibility to access *f2* other than changing its name.

Do I miss something simple? Or is this a design that's so terrible that it's not usable at all?

Comment: This question gets asked routinely. No, you can't access f2.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it does? I could not find it out there but it's what I figured myself. Well guess this question has a short lifecycle then.

Comment: Depends on whether any of us can find a dupetarget. :-)

Comment: I'll keep looking for one myself :)

Comment: A tricky question. I don't think that this is possible. I guess the Java designers wanted to encourage us to use a better design ;)